# System::String^ cast to const char* does not store properly in an external variable

Tags: string, forms, c++-cli, extern

I'm trying to obtain the name of a file in a Windows Forms object and then using that string at another c++ file. The problems comes out when sometimes it gets the correct name, and sometimes it doesn't (returning "îϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸîϸî...")

Am I doing something wrong?

### DECLARATION

```
(B.h)
external const char* imgfilename;
(B.cpp)
const char* imgfilename;
```

### GETTING FILENAME (Form1.h)

```
OpenFileDialog ^openFile = gcnew OpenFileDialog();

if ( openFile->ShowDialog() == Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK ) {

    // Cast from System::String^ to const char*
    msclr::interop::marshal_context^ context = gcnew msclr::interop::marshal_context();

    // imgfilename is an external const char* from B.h included here
    imgfilename = context->marshal_as<const char* > ( openFile->FileName );

}
```

### CHECKING FILENAME (B.cpp)

```
 if ((imgfilename[0] < 'A') || (imgfilename[0] >  'Z')) {       // Out of A-Z
    if ((imgfilename[0] < 'a') || (imgfilename[0] >  'z')) {    // Out of a-z
        msclr::interop::marshal_context^ context = gcnew msclr::interop::marshal_context();
        MessageBox::Show("Error loading image"+
            "\nFile name: "+context->marshal_as<String^> (imgfilename));
    }
 }
```

From time to time with no apparent reason, it doesn't return the correct string. The code does not modify this variable during the program.

Comment: This is not C++, please re-tag it as C++-CLI or C++-CX.

Comment: The C++ tag is for the B file, which stores the external variable I want to use. The other one is C++ CLI (Forms). Anyway, let me know if I must change it anyway, thanks

Comment: I see a `gcnew` in your *B.cpp*, so that's still C++-CLI. I'd say re-tag the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `marshal_context` to marshal to `char*`, the `char*` is only valid until the `marshal_context` is garbage collected. After that, the memory is liable to be overwritten at any point.

There are three possible changes you can make here:

1. Switch `imgfilename` to be `String^` instead of `char*`. (Best, but I assume you have a reason not to do this.)
2. Store the `marshal_context` somewhere, and keep it around longer. (Easier)
3. Instead of using `marshal_context` and `marshal_as`, use `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi`. (Better)

Using `StringToHGlobalAnsi` is preferred because it doesn't hide what's going on with the memory allocations. It is a little bit more work, because you have to remember to free the memory yourself.

```
OpenFileDialog ^openFile = gcnew OpenFileDialog();

if ( openFile->ShowDialog() == Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
{
    if(imgfilename != nullptr)
        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(imgfilename));

    // Cast from System::String^ to const char*
    imgfilename = (char*) Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(openFile->FileName).ToPointer();
}
```

Comment: 4: `marshal_as< std::string >`, probably better than `StringToHGlobalAnsi`.

Comment: I tried the third solution, but it comes out with a compiler error:

error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'System::IntPtr'

at the line: Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(imgfilename));

Comment: In fact, the second option seems to go OK for me, thank you so much ^^